# Как вернуться на шаг назад от пути файла

Tags: c#, консоль

*P.S: Случился дичайший затуп(*
Вот у меня есть путь к файлу:

> E:\Office Installers\ProPlus2021Retail\Office\Data\User File

Путь к файлам получаю через `Directory.EnumerateFiles`
Я хочу получить от файла вернуться назад до папки Data, проверить файл "Installer", если его нет, то вернуться ещё на шаг назад.
Или как вообще можно сделать шаг или 2 шага назад, я так полагаю через сплит можно сделать `Split("/")` но что-то не понимаю уже ничего.

```
foreach (var files in Directory.EnumerateFiles("paths array", "User File", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
   Console.WriteLine(files);
}
```

Comment: У вас файл с именем `User File`?

Comment: @tym32167, ага, ну имеется в виду без расширения

Comment: Добавлю, что можно использовать `Path.GetFullPath("..", path)`, чтобы получить из относительного пути абсолютный с "шагом назад"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не нужно парсить и конкатенировать пути руками. Для этого есть ряд статических и обычных классов в пространстве имён `System.IO`.

В вашем случае или сразу заюзать `Directory.GetParent`

```
string inputPath = @"E:\Office Installers\ProPlus2021Retail\Office\Data\User File";
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(inputPath));

//OUTPUT:
E:\Office Installers\ProPlus2021Retail\Office\Data
```

Либо явно создать объект `DirectoryInfo`

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(inputPath);
Console.WriteLine(dir?.FullName);
while (dir != null)
{
    dir = dir.Parent;
    Console.WriteLine(dir?.FullName ?? "Reached the root directory...");
}

//OUTPUT:
E:\Office Installers\ProPlus2021Retail\Office\Data\User File
E:\Office Installers\ProPlus2021Retail\Office\Data
E:\Office Installers\ProPlus2021Retail\Office
E:\Office Installers\ProPlus2021Retail
E:\Office Installers
E:\
Reached the root directory...
```